# Can i deploy discourse forum on deb11 with bare ip address?

Tags: linux, lamp, discourse

I have apache2 server on deb11 and i want to deploy moodle, wordpress and discourse.
I set up ssl and ports first two but i got issues for discourse.
I need to serve discourse with bare address like the others (xxx.xxx.xx.xx/discourse)

I tried to deploy discourse, trying to give just ip address but it didnt work.